# How do I extend/pad a CDF plot (using seaborn.ecdfplot) to the x-axis limits?

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, seaborn

This code:

```
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'distribution_1': np.random.randn(N),
                'distribution_2': np.random.randn(N)
                })
df['distribution_2'] = df['distribution_2'] / 2
df = df.melt(value_vars=['distribution_1', 'distribution_2'], value_name='value', var_name='distribution')
g = sns.ecdfplot(data=df, x='value', hue='distribution')
g.set(ylim=(-.1, 1.1))
```

yields a figure like this:

[image: Example of the orange CDF not being extended to the limits of the axis]

The CDFs of both distributions do not extend to the limits of the x-axis. I would like to know how to do this. In ggplot2 there is a boolean flag called `pad` that does this (see e.g. [REF](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_ecdf.html)).

This is also possible in seaborn? (I was unable to find it ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.ecdfplot()` doesn't seem to support such an option.  As a workaround, you could loop through the generated lines, and move the endpoints. (Also note that `sns.ecdfplot` doesn't return a `FacetGrid`, but a subplot. Naming the return value `g` might be a bit confusing when comparing to code in example and tutorials.)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'distribution_1': np.random.randn(N),
                   'distribution_2': np.random.randn(N) / 2})
df = df.melt(value_vars=['distribution_1', 'distribution_2'], value_name='value', var_name='distribution')
ax = sns.ecdfplot(data=df, x='value', hue='distribution', palette='winter')
ax.set_ylim(-.1, 1.1)
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
for line in ax.lines:
    x = line.get_xdata()
    x[0] = xmin
    x[-1] = xmax
    line.set_xdata(x)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.ecdfplot with padding]